# Name the reputations and abilities to it

Tags: discussion, support

I’m asking this because, I want to know how many reputations I need to get a rank, and if there is the ultimate rank? And, can you name to every rank each ability for it? Like for example, I want to become a moderator and I need at to have 10.000 reputations and the ability for this are “this” and “this”. Can you name them including the reputations and abilities for each rank?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Your link is related, but not, I think, a duplicate.

Comment: Well, [it prominently contains the same information as your answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPAPo.png), so that seems difficult to justify.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - It's early for me. Conceded.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites probably is worth a read too. Also, in addition to the ones listed, you get a nice surprise at 100k, and I believe 250k :)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ooo, hopefully I can earn 100k reputations so that I can see what is the surprise:)))) What should I do with this post? Can you please show me To how improve it in a proper manner this one?

Comment: Oh, they ship you a swag pack for many sites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the "Recent Achievements" icon in the top-right corner of the screen, you will see a link to "Privileges".

[image: Achievements pulldown, pulled down]

If you click on that link, you will see the [list of privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) available for that stack (the previous link is for specifically meta.stackexchange.com; each stack has its own list), and the amount of reputation needed to achieve each one.